# Tensorflow per channel quantization

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Using the current Tensorflow [quantization ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization), how would I go about simulating **per-channel** quantization during inference? This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08342.pdf) defines **per-layer** quantization as

> We can specify a single quantizer (defined by the scale and zero-point) for an entire tensor referred to as per-layer quantization

and **per-channel** quantization as

> Per-channel quantization has a different scale and offset for each convolutional kernel.

Let's assume we have this *subgraph*

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.random.uniform(size=500*80*64*1)
      .astype('float32')
      .reshape(500, 80, 64, 1)
W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', 9, 5, 1, 96],
                    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
h1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
```

Under the current APIs present, I would probably do something like this to simulate **per-layer** quantization at the inference time

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.random.uniform(size=500*80*64*1)
      .astype('float32')
      .reshape(500, 80, 64, 1)
min_x = tf.reduce_min(x)
max_x = tf.reduce_max(x)

W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', 9, 5, 1, 96],
                    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
min_W1 = tf.reduce_min(W1)
max_W1 = tf.reduce_max(W1)

qX = tf.quantize(A, min_X, max_X, tf.quint8, mode='MIN_FIRST')
qW = tf.quantize(W, min_W, max_W, tf.quint8, mode='MIN_FIRST')

# This is how one would simulate per layer quantization for convolution.
qAW = tf.nn.quantized_conv2d(qX[0], qW[0], qX[1], qX[2], qW[1], qW[2], 
strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
```

My question is how would I simulate per channel quantization? As I understand the [tf.quantization.quantize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/quantize) is actually doing **per-layer** quantization and not **per-channel** quantization. Also, the `tf.nn.quantized_conv2d` is actually doing quantized-layer-input to quantized-layer-kernels convolutions.

As per my understanding of **per-channel** quantization, there would be `k`, `output_min` and `output_max`. Where `k` is `96` in my example (the number of kernels, analogous to this [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/quantize) ).

Are there any existing Ops in tensorflow that can handle **per-channel** quantization or is there a way of making it work with existing ops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment there is no way to simulate per channel quantization inference on tflite. 
As i see, tensorflow developers nowadays are implementing [experimental symmetric per channel quantization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/c021fc53415681f071727a7ac87747e3fdf23585#diff-4e94df4d2961961ba5f69bbd666e0552). But there is no ways to test it

Comment: it seems per-layer quantization will be deprecated on tflite, and per-channel quantization is by default is there anyhow possible to have that feature or ideally both on tflite somehow?